# Handling JSON file with python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm developing a plugin for sublime text and I'm have some problems handling a json file.

**This is the json file**

```
{
   "desktop":{
      "name":"build",
      "upload":{
         "maximum":512,
      },
      "load":{
         "core":"i7",
      }
   },
   "table":{
      "name":"clean",
      "upload":{
         "maximum":1024,
      },
      "load":{
         "core":"i3",
      }
   }
}
```

**An this is how I load it**

```
with open(self.path, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    datas = json.loads(text)

    for data in datas:
        print(data['desktop'])
```

**The output show me this error**

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

But when I try with `data[0]` I get one character from the json file.

I know I'm doing something wrong with the parse and encoding, but I don't know where. I been all day reading previous posts from here and trying to figure out what is the right way to do it.

I'll apreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand that this is not a JSON array. This is a json object -

```
{
   "desktop":{
      "name":"build",
      "upload":{
         "maximum":512,
      },
      "load":{
         "core":"i7",
      }
   },
   "table":{
      "name":"clean",
      "upload":{
         "maximum":1024,
      },
      "load":{
         "core":"i3",
      }
   }
}
```

so the code -

```
for data in datas:
    print(data['desktop'])
```

is not iterating through the array items, it is actually iterating through the properties/attributes of that object `datas`.
So doing this gives you item already -

```
for data in datas:
    print(datas[data])
```

but if you want to manipulate and find each attribute you can check like this -

```
for data in datas:
    print(data)
    print(datas[data])

    if data == 'desktop':
        print('do somthing')
```

Here is an online view of it- https://repl.it/B61g

**EDIT**

If `datas` can be array or object, you can check like this -

```
if type(datas) is list:
    # datas is list do whatever you like
else:
    # datas is obj
```

Comment: Thanks _brainless coder_ for your explanation was very useful to understand what I was doing wrong. I think I was confusing because I was handling a Json array, so when tried with this, I forgot the diference.

Comment: There is a easiest way to convert that json object in a json array? I know the way with for loops, but I don't know if there is something simpler.

Comment: check the comment, you can check whether it is a array or not like that

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through a JSON object using a for each loop will give you a key in the json object.
Hence, in your loop data will refer to the string 'desktop' itself (and other keys in the object) and hence when you try to do `data['desktop']` you are actually attempting to get the index of a string but since string indexes must be numbers, it fails

To print the 'desktop' key from the file you can simply write `print(datas['desktop'])`

Comment: Thanks @AdityaBalwani I was confusing it with a Json array as another user commented up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for k, v in datas.iteritems():
   # your stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, _Klaus D_ posted the same in the first coment, It was help full too.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through a dictionary will gave you the keys as strings only. What you might want to have is:

```
for key, value in datas.items()
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: Not quite right... keys can be any hashable object and there is no conversion to string in the enumeration.

Comment: @tdelaney If you parse JSON, it will be a string. I could have pointed out the it relates to that more clearly.

Comment: Your answer helped also, I did not marked as answered, because the other user explained what I was doing wrong, but thanks for your time too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(type(datas))`, you'll see its the outer dict. Enumerating the dict enumerates its keys which are strings. `data` is a string and not surprisingly, `data['desktop']` fails. Many questions are answered with a few well-placed prints!

Answer (score 0):

my case

```
data = res.read() //<<--HTTP DATA
resDic = json.loads(data.decode())
if resDic["code"] == 1000:
    //some thing
```

Try data.decode()

Comment: The problem wasn't in `loads`. This isn't a solution to the problem.

Comment: as @tdelaney said the problem wasn't the `load` but thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "desktop":{
      "name":"build",
      "upload":{
         "maximum":512
      },
      "load":{
         "core":"i7"
      }
   },
   "table":{
      "name":"clean",
      "upload":{
         "maximum":1024
      },
      "load":{
         "core":"i3"
      }
   }
}
```

[image: code image]

json when one of the attributes that should be no comma